# Without Crash Message My table View getting Crash

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

This my code please verify it friends:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSInteger count=[[arrParsingProduct valueForKey:@"description"] count];
    return count;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger count=[[arrParsingProduct valueForKey:@"description"]count];

    return count;

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    productSub=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];

    NSLog(@"entering");
    productSub.lblSubProduct.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrParsingProduct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"description"]];


    return productSub;

}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:LocalImage@"%@",[[arrParsingProduct objectAtIndex:section] valueForKey:@"image"]];
    self.imgHeader.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]]];
    self.lblHeaderproduct.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrParsingProduct objectAtIndex:section] valueForKey:@"name"]];
    self.lblHeaderCost.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrParsingProduct objectAtIndex:section]valueForKey:@"price"]];
    [self.btnHeader addTarget:self action:@selector(touchup:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return self.view;
}
```

There is no crash message. I tried to find out the problem using break point. I have got confused.Please any one tell me what could be the issue?

Comment: "description" in array[arrParsingProduct] contains which value?

Comment: it contain string values @MeghsDhameliya

Comment: i cant see type of your productSub ( UItableViewCell * productSub ), another problem is dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier , you shoud use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifierForIndexPath

Comment: inside array group of dictionary values is there ...@MeghsDhameliya

Comment: that is table view cell class @MohamadFarhand

Comment: thats the problem 1) numberOfSectionsInTableView and 2) cellForRowAtIndexPath both method expect return value as a int not string, for the test purpose set static value eg. return 1;

Comment: @KishoreKumar please add exeption breakpoint to find the problem :)

Comment: but i have getting the count of that values @MeghsDhameliya,but i will check as per your requirement..

Comment: have you set cell identifier "cell1"

Comment: in viewForHeaderInSection you are  returning self.view; thats not the right way create UIView object and return that one. or just return nil for now

Comment: s you are correct if i make that as nil ...its working..

Comment: @MeghsDhameliya i have created my header view via story board then how i will return the uiview for header in section.

Comment: Create object of that Viewcontroller and return objViewcontroller.view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89054/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-meghs-dhameliya).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in viewForHeaderInSection you are returning self.view; thats not the right way create UIView object and return that one.

```
UIStoryboard *objStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ViewController *objVC = [objStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"headerView_identifier"];
return objVC.view;
```